# Transactions & write performance when calling function externally

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have a stored function that I call from a python script (using psycopg2) which on average executes about 10 UPDATE or INSERT statements. iostat shows that I hit 15k writes/second often and 100% util.

I'm hoping I can change a few things to reduce those iostat numbers as I need that function to run as quickly as possible.

What is the best strategy regarding transactions and functions in this situation? When should I be executing a commit?

I recall reading somewhere that calling I stored function like this automatically begins and ends a transaction for me. Would it be better to do something else like insert all the function parameters into a table that acts as a queue and I modify my function to read that table in and do its work?

Output from a link in the comments,

```
version                      | PostgreSQL 9.1.3 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51), 64-bit
checkpoint_completion_target | 0.9
checkpoint_segments          | 32
client_encoding              | UTF8
default_statistics_target    | 100
effective_cache_size         | 8GB
lc_collate                   | en_US.UTF-8
lc_ctype                     | en_US.UTF-8
log_destination              | stderr
log_rotation_age             | 1d
log_rotation_size            | 0
log_truncate_on_rotation     | on
logging_collector            | on
maintenance_work_mem         | 64MB
max_connections              | 30
max_stack_depth              | 2MB
port                         | 5432
server_encoding              | UTF8
shared_buffers               | 4GB
synchronous_commit           | off
temp_buffers                 | 128MB
TimeZone                     | US/Eastern
wal_buffers                  | 16MB
work_mem                     | 128MB
```

Comment: Everything in one function execution is automatically part of a single transaction. I can't give much advice without knowing more about the table structures, PostgreSQL tuning, OS, file system, and file placement. (As one example of what I *don't* know: have you moved your pg_xlog directory to a separate filesystem? One a separate RAID? On a separate controller?)

Comment: It's all on a 2 drive RAID1, xlog not on a separate filesystem. I know this should be changed and I've got plans to do so. For the moment however I'd like to ensure that I'm using transactions properly and not doing anything that is obviously wrong.

Comment: Without knowing more, I'd have to say that 15,000 writes per second on two spindles is pretty good. You may need to add more spindles to do a lot better.  You could probably squeeze a little bit more out with configuration changes, if you haven't done much there yet. If you post the results of running the query on this page, I might be able to post something worth putting as a proper answer: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Server_Configuration

Comment: I've updated my post. FYI the system has 16gb of RAM.

Comment: You've clearly done your homework; it's no wonder you're getting such good performance from only two spindles. If you need to boost write performance, improving your disk subsystem is probably the main area to look at. On the machines where we're handling high load, we have a mirror for the OS, a mirror for xlog, and about a lot of spindles for the data directory. On separate controllers, all with BBU cache configured for write-back. You could look at asynchronous commits if you can tolerate a few seconds of transactions lost in a hard OS crash, but otherwise, you're looking good to me.

Comment: Great thanks. So is there a better strategy than calling this function over and over from a psycopg2 script? If I had longer transactions that did more work as opposed to many small transactions?

Comment: That could help some, but I would be surprised if it yielded more than a 5% increase. Increasing `checkpoint_segments` and/or `checkpoint_timeout` might also help a little, because it would reduce the number of full page writes (which occur for the first WAL-logging of a page after a checkpoint).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to kgrittin's suggestions to improve the disk subsystem, I want to make a point about transactions.  Transactions force an fsync  on the WAL so the fewer commits the fewer physical writes are forced.    In general the logical grouping of transactions is more important than the performance, but it does mean that longer transactions, provided they don't wait on eachother, will perform better than a larger number of shorter transactions.